# How to stop fedora from notifying me about nodejs updates?

Tags: fedora, node.js, npm

I installed nodejs using dnf on fedora 25, then removed and installed the package from nodejs' website.

I excluded npm from dnf. Dnf stopped notifying me about npm updates but the software center is still notifying me.

Should I exclude npm from yum as well or what? It's annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora's package management system is meant to treat your system as composed out of a consistent set of RPMs. If you go outside of that, there's no really good way for it to handle that. You've attempted to work around this by excluding the package, but this can cause other problems (what if a different package actually requires that system version of NPM, for example).

So, instead, I'd suggest this:

Install your own NPM into `/usr/local/`, `/opt`, or `/home/lynob/whatever`. Adjust your paths and scripts to use that for your own stuff. Ignore the system npm completely; either don't install it, or else if installed, don't use it for the software you want the upstream version for.

Answer (score 3):

Complex answer for this topic is explained on [AskFedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23741/how-do-i-make-the-software-updater-skipexclude-some-packages/), but in short, you just disabled the updates in DNF. The GUI is called PackageKit and [ignores the DNF configuration](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1256108#c9). But it honors the `exclude` directive in the repo files, so you should add

```
exclude=npm
```

to the end of `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo`.

But is not there something wrong that upstream `nodejs` is providing older (lower version) of RPMs? Or their versioning is just wrong/different? Or you just want to stay on specific version?

Comment: I did so and also added that to `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` and I tried `exclude=npm` too, it didn't work. The older version offered by RPM caused issues when installing Jhipster and couldn't update it using `npm install -g npm`. The fact that npm could update itself easily means I don't need to manage it using a package manager, thus there's no need to have the lower version. Plus I don't have to see stupid errors like `npm WARN deprecated minimatch`

Comment: Try also `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo`

Comment: Tried that too, nothing seems to work